# How do i access the methods for the Virtual Reality addon?

Tags: add-on

I want to access the methods for the add-on of virtual reality viewpoint. How would i do this. I have previously did the hover over the ui, and take the code from there but it did not work. are there an suggestions on what i should do?

Comment: Oh, by the way, when you said it did not work, what did it do?  Did it give you an error?

Comment: yeah it gives me a error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the error says: "RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.virtual_reality_display.poll() failed context is incorrect"

Comment: It sounds like you need to do something before you can run this.

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: what code are you talking about?

Comment: Are you just running this: bpy.ops.view3d.virtual_reality_display.poll()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the problem is.  I looked at the code for the virtual reality addon, and it wants a context argument for `bpy.ops.view3d.virtual_reality_display.poll()` Now unfortunately, I don't know what it wants for that argument, so you'll have to figure that out. 
Hope this helps!

UPDATE:
context MIGHT be `bpy.context`, but I can't test it so I'm not sure.